# Jmeter Recorder - can't access github website

Tags: automation, jmeter, automated-tests, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to Jmeter and I have the following case:

I'm trying to record using Jmeter by going to github.com/login. I set localhost and port to jmeter, also to Mozilla. Certificate created by jmeter is added to mozilla.

If I access for example stackoverflow, it works, but if I want to go to github I don't have the button Accept the risk and continue as it was for stackoverflow, therefore github can't be accessed. I even installed a clean Mozilla in order to not have any old certificate for github.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

[jmeter configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt4h6.png)

[github certificate message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZX9d.png)

[firefox proxy config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QEn8.png)

Later edit: This is how it looks for example
[stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZMa6.png)

I'm not able to access facebook, google besides github.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of certificate installation. Once you install the certificate, there shouldn't be an "Accept the risk and continue". Rather you should be able to directly navigate to the website.

Please try the below steps to install appropriately in Firefox

```
Launch Firefox -> Navigate to Options -> Search Certificates -> Click View Certificates -> Click on "Authorities" tab -> Click Import ->  Choose certificate file types to include ".crt" files in the File Browser Pop-up -> Choose "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt"
```

Pop-up such as this should appear if you have followed appropriately

[image]

```
Check Trust this CA to identify Websites -> Click OK -> Navigate to Authorities tab once again -> Ensure JMeter certificate is available
```

If all the above steps are followed, you should be able to record https://github.com/login without any hiccups

---

**Why this error appears in the first place**

Basically when a browser tries to access a website via HTTPS, it tries to establish a secure connection post validation of the SSL certificate. In our case, since JMeter is the proxy with which Firefox interacts, Firefox believes it is the actual server and hence it is trying its best to ensure your safety by preventing you from sending the request since JMeter's SSL certificate is not one of the approved SSLs (not part of Trusted CA certificates).

---

**How the certificate helps**

When you add the JMeter's Root CA certificate into Trusted CA folder, you let Firefox know that SSL provided by JMeter is trustworthy and hence things are alright

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already did what you wrote, as I told in question. That's why I am able to visit some other websites, but not github.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to import JMeter's certificate into Firefox browser in order to be able to intercept and decrypt secure traffic, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation for more details.
2. Remember that JMeter's MITM certificate has limited lifetime (7 days as of [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html)), so it might be the case you need to re-import the certificate if it's expired. The lifetime of the certificate is controlled by `proxy.cert.validity` property
3. If you still experience problems try [cleaning your browser history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox) and remove everything from the beginning of the time, it will remove cached certificates as well

More information: [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

Also be aware that you can use an alternative way of recording a JMeter test - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates

Comment: Certificate was added as I already said in the question. I am able to visit other websites but not github. Firefox browser was installed from scratch in order to not have any history, I even deleted the folder that remained after deletion.